# Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.QueryCollection' from assembly Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http, Version=3.1.5.0

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I am trying to upgrade my API project from .net core 2.2 to .net core 3.1
And I meet this exception when write unittest using xunit.
Exception throw on:

```
Mock<IHttpContextAccessor> mockupHttpContextAccessor = new Mock<IHttpContextAccessor>();

            mockupHttpContextAccessor.SetupProperty(x => x.HttpContext.User, new ClaimsPrincipal(_identity));
            mockupHttpContextAccessor.SetupProperty(x => x.HttpContext.Request.Query, new QueryCollection(new Dictionary<string, StringValues>()
            {
                { "userId", new StringValues( Guid.NewGuid().ToString() ) }
            }));
```

Message:

> System.TypeLoadException : Could not load type
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.QueryCollection' from assembly
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http, Version=3.1.5.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.

Comment: Internal? That's not in the namespace? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.querycollection?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: It's reference from one project using .NetStandard 2.1

Comment: If you reference an internal type like that, you have to expect compatibility problems.

Comment: [Stop using these "pubternal" APIs in ASP.NET Core 3.0 project.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/2.2-3.1#new-behavior). 
 The APIs are marked with the internal access modifier and can no longer be used by code outside that assembly. You could try  [QueryCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.querycollection?view=aspnetcore-3.1).